# Jquery basic function test call is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, jsp

My Jsp is ,

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%-- <%@include file="include.jsp"%> --%>

<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="../tld/spring-form.tld"%>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery/jqueryChat.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <input type="text" id="test" name="test" />
    <input type="button" value="Ajax Submit" onclick="madeAjaxCall()">
</body>
</html>
```

My JqueryChat.js will be .,

```
function madeAjaxCall(){
    alert("Hello 99");
    alert($("#test").val());
}
```

When I click the button I am getting the error as ,

[image]

I need to get the value of the text-box in the alert.

Good answers are definitely appreciated.

Comment: Does this error occur in reliable browsers too?

Comment: please specify the JS error you are getting in the console..

Comment: You didn't include the code where the error occurs...

Comment: try this  <input type="text" id="test" name="test" />
    <input type="button" value="Ajax Submit" onclick="madeAjaxCall($(test))">



function madeAjaxCall(obj){
    alert("Hello 99");
    alert($(obj).val());
}

Comment: I don't see any issue in the code, working JS fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/55xcz/

Comment: No response from other browers.

Comment: is firefox/chrome has the same error

Comment: This is a working code. Try to upgrade your OS and browser.         Internet Explorer = Google Chrome Downloader.

Comment: No errors and alerts are shown in other browsers .

Comment: page has no doctype and therefore will run in quirks mode

Comment: @charlietfl Is it neccessary yo put doctype ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you need to call jquery object onload before you are using on click event here..As $(document).ready().So only ist

Answer (score 0):

The following code works perfectly for me.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#button").click(function(){
        alert("Hello 99");
        alert($("#test").val());
    });
});

</script>

</head>
<body>

    <input type="text" id="test" name="test" />
    <input type="button" id="button" value="Ajax Submit">
</body>
</html>
```

1. Check if your jquery.js and jqueryChat.js are downloaded from proper place.
2. Put your JS code in `$(document).ready(function() { .. });`
3. Use `$("#button").click(function(){` instead of

> onclick="madeAjaxCall()"